# PHP MySQL query by date, increment/decrement date

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

I have a database with a timetable.
ie

```
Class  Start     Day 
Yoga   9:00:00   1,2,3
Golf   13:00:00  2,5,6
etc...
```

where Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2, 
      etc.

I can currently display the activities for today perfectly well, and want to add a way to display the activities for yesterday(and the day before, the day before, etc...) and Tomorrow (and the day after, and the day after...)

I have been trying with Javascript and ajax (I am only starting out learning any sort of web design and languages). It seems to me that this should be a very simple task but I can't figure out what I'm missing. This is the code for getting today's activities:

```
<?php
//Create a connection
$con = mysqli_connect(
    "*********",            //host
    "*********",        //username
    "*********",            //password
    "*********"         //dbname
);

//check connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

//check if server is active
if(!mysqli_ping($con)){
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
}

$result = mysqli_query($con, "
    SELECT *
    FROM schedules
    ORDER BY Start ASC //Start time of event
");

/* print the Current Day in the Format:
    Day, Month, Year
*/
echo "<h1 align='center'>".date('l, F j, Y') . "</h1><br>";
//todays date
$current_day = date('N');

echo "<ul data-role='listview' data-inset='true'>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    //if the event is on today then print the details
    if(strpos($row['Day'], $current_day) !== false){
        echo "<li>";

        echo "<h1>".$row['Start']." - ".$row['End']."</h1>";
        echo "<h2>".$row['Class']."</h2>";
        echo "<h2>".$row['Instructor']."</h2>";

        echo "</li>";
    }
}
echo "</ul>";

//close connection
mysqli_close($con)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better solution would be to separate those fields in your database, rather than storing multiple values in a single field. But here's a way to make this work with your current design. First, define a yesterday and tomorrow variable, being careful not to spill over onto 0 or 8. I use the ternary operator to keep it concise:

```
 $yesterday = (($current_day-1)!=0) ? ($current_day-1) : 7;
 $tomorrow = (($current_day+1)!=8) ? ($current_day+1) : 1;
```

Then update your while block as necessary:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    //if the event is on today then print the details
    if(strpos($row['Day'], $current_day) !== false){
        echo "<li>";

        echo "<h1>".$row['Start']." - ".$row['End']."</h1>";
        echo "<h2>".$row['Class']."</h2>";
        echo "<h2>".$row['Instructor']."</h2>";

        echo "</li>";
    }

    if(strpos($row['Day'], $yesterday) !== false){
        //do stuff
    }

    if(strpos($row['Day'], $tomorrow) !== false){
        //do stuff
    }

}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: That makes sense on the PHP side.
For the client side I cant seem to get it to set yesterday or tomorrow.

Comment: What do you want the output on the client side to look like?

Comment: I would like it to have three buttons in the header navbar, A button for Yesterday, today and tomorrow. It would display the events on that day. Once tomorrow is clicked it will show the next day, if tomorrow is clicked again it will show the next day after that. 
At the minute I am just using a form with Monday through Sunday in a menu. I just think the button option would be cleaner.